# Look for specific files in folder w/ VBA

Tags: vba

I have a macro that loops through each file in a folder and do some things if the file has the today's date in its name.

Here is a piece of the code:

```
For Each objFile In objFolder.Files

If Left(objFile.Name, 8) = Format(Date, "dd-mm-yy") Then


        currSheet = Mid(objFile.Name, 10, 4)
        Sheets(currSheet).Activate
        'LastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        'ActiveSheet.Range("A1:D" & LastRow).Clear
        With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
            "TEXT;" & FolderName & objFile.Name _
            , Destination:=Range("$A$1"))
            .Name = Left(objFile.Name, Len(objFile.Name) - 4)
           '. 
           '.
           '.
End If
Next objFile
```

I've just realized that it takes around 60 seconds to find the today's files, because it loops through all files in folder (around 0.1 second per file, but there's a lot of files).

I'd like to find files with the following names (only for today's date), I will run this macro once a day, for example:

```
30-07-18 CA01 NEGS.txt
30-07-18 CA02 NEGS.txt
30-07-18 CA03 NEGS.txt
30-07-18 CA04 NEGS.txt
```

So I know the name pattern.
There's a maximum of 4 files in the same date.
So it would be great if I could search only these files (and check if it exists), instead of loop through all files. Is is possible to do it? Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: And what, pray tell, is the host folder?

Comment: Unless you have a very large number of files in the folder, or the folder is a network share, I think it rather unlikely that you'll see any benefits from this kind of optimization; I would suggest that you confirm that this is the problem by first loading all the relevant filenames into a collection and then run your processing loop over the collection; check how long it takes to build up the collection.

Comment: You're right. I have thousand of files in the folder, in this case this optimization was very relevant. I tested how long it takes to loop though all files and it's ~60 seconds. Now I'm using @Domenic 's solution and it takes only 2 or 3 seconds to run the whole macro!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Dir function accepts wildcards, and can return the file names that match a specified pattern.  Here's an example...

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim strPath As String
    Dim strFile As String
    Dim strPattern As String

    strPattern = Format(Date, "dd-mm-yy")

    strPath = "C:\Users\Domenic\Desktop\"

    strFile = Dir(strPath & strPattern & "*.txt", vbNormal)
    Do While Len(strFile) > 0
        'Do stuff
        '
        '
        strFile = Dir
    Loop

End Sub
```